# How does India's BJP maintain party discipline over 180 million party members?

Tags: parties, india, bureaucracy, party-discipline, bjp

Being the world's largest political party, with such an enormous membership roll, the methods and techniques used by the BJP to maintain discipline must necessarily be very effective for any coherent party policy to form.

Otherwise with over 180 million folks, it's difficult to imagine the party could have stayed in power since 2014 as India's ruling party.

But it's also difficult to imagine a standard hierarchical party structure, since there would need to be so many layers in the hierarchy, if organized in the normal fashion, that intra-party feuds would almost certainly predominate.

There isn't much available literature in English as to how this balancing act was accomplished. Can anyone shed some insight?

Comment: Why can't there be disagreements and feuds and them still remaining in power? Isn't the purpose of a political party to find people with similar ideals even if you don't agree on everything?  It seems to me that they are staying in power because they still have similar goals and people don't feel the need to leave the party.

Comment: That's under four times as large as the second-largest democratic party, the Democratic Party of the United States (not counting the Communist Party of China because it's so different in major respects). Who is to say that managing it represents a fundamentally different challenge, such that it requires a far more complicated hierarchy?

Comment: @Obie2.0 The Democratic Party of the US is known for quite complex internal processes. Quadrupling that would imply that the BJP membership spends the vast majority of its time on internal matters. Is that true?

Comment: @JoeW Well the party leaders obviously can't spend 100% of their day on such matters and still remain in power. Since government work takes some non-zero amount of time. Even if they spend only 75% of their time on internal party matters, that leaves only 25% of a 16 hour waking day for everything else. Which does not seem sustainable. In practice it's difficult to imagine how they balance the competing demands, hence my question.

Comment: It doesn't all have to fall to the party leaders to resolve and when you have a party that large you also have a lot more people to help solve any issues that may arise. Still not sure why having more members is an issue for them staying in power.

Comment: @JoeW  If there are X layers of subordinate managers/regional leaders/etc. underneath a party leader, that doesn't mean the party leader can just deal exclusively with the layer immediately below them. And ignore the X-1 layers of subordinates further down the hierarchy. In practice all X layers of subordinates will try to compete for attention, likely in intra-party factional groupings.

Comment: It also doesn’t mean that they are the only ones who can.

Comment: How can party with 100'00s members manage the same issue? How many layer do you expect them to have? the big jump in hierarchy is going from 10 to 10'000, afterward is not that big, it is just more people in the same (bottom) layers

Comment: @EarlGrey 1 layer of middle management is a lot different from 5 layers of middle management. For example, intra-middle management conflicts become possible.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo exactly. A party with 100'000s members has already the same issue. As I said, the big jump is from 10 (1 layer) to 10'000 (4 layers or even more).

Comment: @EarlGrey, I don't see your rationale? clearly 100 million people means 100 million ^ 100 million possible combinations of issues, whereas 100 000 is only 100 00 ^ 100 000. A vastly different number.

Comment: More issues you have, the less important they are. The weight of each one of the issues is even more diluted, making each one of them even more irrelevant to party leadership. So the bottom 2-3 layers do not do anything and have no influence whatsoever on the top 2-3 layers. 
See the chinese only party domination: it does not matter what are the issues of the population of China, the only pressing issues that are considered are the needs of a small ring of powerful people.

Comment: @EarlGrey This doesn't seem to make sense? Human issues can be multiplicative or additive last time I checked.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo It may not make sense in your reference system, but the topic of the number of parties (and therefore on the weight of their internal opinions) is highly debated among political scientist. For a starter, I suggest you to read this paper:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/40711882 as well as the book "The tyranny of the two-party system" and the article citing it: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12408304511929026653&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=de

Comment: @EarlGrey Any 'reference system' where human issues can be multiplicative or additive would include nearly all that I've ever heard of. 100 million people disputing may dilute the importance of each individual dispute, but when combined is a vastly more serious set of disputes then 100 000 people disputing.

Answer (score 10):

> maintain party discipline over 180 million party members

Why would there be a need to "control" the rank and file members, which is what most of those 180M people are?  People should be free to a) leave party membership and b) vote as they see fit when party elections take place.

When party members assume positions of leadership within a party, get elected or seek office office on party lists - or potentially, just claim to speak on behalf of a party - then, yes parties *may* need various mechanisms to keep them aligned, in the interest of the party, its values and its electoral prospects.

But that's not at the 180M level and it is much dependent on how many positions of leadership and influence are to be found within a party and how many elected officials it has.

I am sure the BJP encounters some challenges due to its size.  Perhaps that would be an interesting question to ask.  This answer however is only concerned with a frameshift:  *controlling* rank and file is not what a proper democratic party should be concerned about.

Comment: That is a good point, you really only need to keep members in line when they reach a certain level in elected offices or in party position. It doesn't matter as much what the average member is doing.

Comment: All parties must control the rank and file to some extent, if at the very least to ensure sufficient voters turnout in at risk districts. Assuming there is an ambition to form a majority government. Electoral participation is high enough in India with viable enough opposition parties, and the voting age population so massive, that even with 180 million the BJP would likely need to mobilize nearly 100% of their party membership in certain regions.

Comment: Encouraging voting turnout by party members is *very* different from *party member discipline*.  There is nothing untoward on that.  But if that was the question you meant to ask you should have been more specific.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't see how? There will always be some percentage of the membership otherwise indisposed on Election Day in any country for a variety of reasons. So if the BJP needs close to 100% turnout to win in a certain district, that implies they have to ensure sufficient discipline in nearly 100% of the membership in that district, regardless of their personal matters or other obligations on Election Day. That seems like the dictionary definition of 'discipline'.

Answer (score 4):

I don't how many of the people involved in this discussion are actually from India, but I am from India, rural India to be specific and I have seen many political party's membership rollouts in person.

as @user366122 said "they don't" is actually true to some extent.

the situation in india isn't something like when people find their ideas resonating with some leader's and then they decide to join party. - Nope that's not the case here, Political parties actively run campaigns to get people registered as their party members on the pretext of something in return for them.

The 180M number that you see in the news is too exaggerated because at least half of them don't involve in any of the activities related to the party. They are "just registered members". This category consists of wide variety of people - from early voters (18+ teenagers) to 70+ senior citizens.

You might think, when they don't do anything in the party why join party. There are multiple reasons for this:

1. Youngsters just want to join gangs. Here they are political gangs.
2. Middle agers just want to be on the safe side in case of any troubles or risks by conforming with their social groups. So, they just signup as a member, join some WhatsApp groups and spend their free time in forwarding all they receive in that group to all the other groups.
3. Senior citizens are often fooled on the pretext on some benefit. Or the people who are in charge of registering new members will simply say that the registration is something related to some new government scheme, and everybody has to do it. (Yes, that's true, I have personally confronted fellows like that who told all the senior citizens in our street that they will get life insurance if they register as members).

In India a simple statement like "Everyone is doing it So, you should do it" can literally make people do it. The fear of being treated as an outsider if we don't join common stance is very real in us.

As far as the BJP concerned, the number of people who actively involved in the party's activities is way less than 180M. So, I don't think it really employs some serious techniques to maintain the structure of the party.

And the organizations associated with them will do most of the work. (It's quite debatable whether the organizations are associated with the party or party is an associate to the organization)

Very few internal fighting incidents came out of the party recently, but all of them are covered up for now, and it is only a matter of time all such things compound and explode.

If some other party wins the next elections, you will definitely see their numbers rise to 180M or more. And it is the same thing all over again.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! Has there been any pushback in rural communities to these recruitment tactics? Especially number 3 sounds like it would actually incite a lot of bad feelings against the BJP folks responsible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are none. cause from their point of view it is safe to align with some political party (mostly it's the current ruling party) than nobody. 
It is not just about BJP, in each state we have different party in power, and everyone does the same thing.

Answer (score -5):

> ***How does India's BJP maintain party discipline over 180 million party members?***

The simple answer is: they don't.

For more information, you can read the following:

- [Vaishnav, Milan; ***When Crime Pays: Money and Muscle in Indian Politics***,  1st edition (January 24, 2017); Yale University Press;](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0300216203)

---

If you watch some specific Bollywood movies (e.g., [Rajneeti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raajneeti), etc.), you will get to understand how Indian politics work.

There are various levels of leaders in the party. The bigger their region of influence, the bigger and stronger the leader is.

The general workers are at the bottom tier. They are either volunteers or paid hands, and they are expendable. The politicians use them to control their legitimate or criminal businesses, keep influence on the respective constituencies, and save them from arrests, etc., by using their political influence. The hands sometimes get involved in crimes without the consent of the politicians, in that case, politicians turn a blind eye to their criminal activities if they are useful tools. Otherwise, they are expended, and new hands fill in their positions.

- [At least 42% (33) of the total 78 ministers in the Prime Minister Narendra Modi-led cabinet at the Centre have declared criminal cases against them](https://www.livemint.com/news/india/in-modi-2-0-cabinet-33-out-of-78-ministers-have-criminal-cases-against-them-report-11625891086118.html)
- [Eight People the Modi Govt Gifted a Get-Out-of-Jail Free Card to Since 2014](https://thewire.in/government/modi-govt-get-out-of-jail-free-card)
- [India’s Modi government approved the release of Bilkis Bano’s rapists](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/10/18/indias-modi-government-approved-release-of-bilkis-banos-rapists)
- [Rape accused BJP MLA given clean chit](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/up-bjp-mla-gets-clean-chit-in-gangrape-case-nephew-arrested/article30888285.ece)

Sometimes, public pressure becomes so huge that the politicians either can't save their criminal hands or gets them arrested temporarily to save their faces.

- [Facing flak for supporting the Kathua rape accused, Chandra Prakash Ganga and Lal Singh submitted their resignations as ministers to state BJP President Sat Sharma](https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/kathua-case-muslim-girl-gang-raped-murdered-in-hindu-temple-chargesheet-rahul-gandhi-midnight-march-against-modi-unnao-10-updates-on-what-happened-in-jammu-118041300145_1.html)

If a politician is not a businessperson, he gets paid by businessmen to return favors, and the payment flows down up to the bottom tier. Thus they maintain a symbiotic relationship.

- [The Billionaire Beneficiaries of BJP’s Schemes](https://www.newsclick.in/BJP-Schemes-Modi-Ambani-Adani-Baba-Ramdev-Indian-Billionaire)
- [Media freedom fears in India after Modi ally Adani buys 29% stake in NDTV](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/24/media-freedom-fears-in-india-after-modi-ally-adani-buys-29-stake-in-ndtv)
- [Arch-rivals BJP, Left unite to back Adani port in Kerala](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/thiruvananthapuram/arch-rivals-bjp-left-unite-to-back-adani-port-in-kerala/articleshow/95239687.cms)
- [With Gautam Adani On Stage, Ashok Gehlot Scores Huge Investment, BJP Digs](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/with-gautam-adani-on-stage-ashok-gehlot-scores-huge-investment-bjp-digs-3413061)
- [A Mukesh Ambani-owned media firm is helping Modi’s BJP win elections in India](https://qz.com/india/2141950/mukesh-ambanis-firm-is-helping-modis-bjp-win-polls-in-india)

---

**Note:** this happens in all over South Asia, not only in India.

**Note:2** I am not a keen observer of Indian politics. So, I can't write a comprehensive and well-arranged answer. This answer is just based on what I occasionally read on the Internet.

Comment: I am not sure a Bollywood movie is good evidence of party control or a lack of it.

Comment: @JoeW, Do u want me to add news references?

Comment: Yes, that would help your answer

Comment: You have seemed to edit in a lot of things about political corruption which has nothing to do with party discipline as it is being asked about in the question. What is being referred to as party discipline is making sure that everyone is working towards the party goal and not doing things that are contrary to that or might hurt the party goals. It has nothing to do with members of the party doing corrupt things or breaking the law.